# How to include rails in Semantic UI framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, semantic-ui

I am trying to add a line of rails code in a html.erb file using the Semantic UI framework. However, I am used to using Twitter bootstrap for web graphic design, and am not very familiar with the Semantic UI framework. Could someone show me how to use rails with Semantic. For instance, how would I insert an erb tag which allows me to go to a certain link within the app when I press a button? Do I include the 'link_to' method in the erb file, or do I use a different link tag for the html.erb code?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways. You can include a gem or insert the css and javascript files of framework directly in your project.

I am using through [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/). In this site, you can search the framework that you want and when you click on version, is showed how to insert into your project.

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-semantic', '~> 2.1.7'
end

# application.scss -> I use SASS instead CSS. In CSS use '*= require semantic'.
@import 'semantic';

# application.js
//= require semantic
```

Now you can use Semantic-UI in your project normaly.

Example of Link:

```
<%= link_to 'New Profile', new_profile_path, class: 'ui blue button' %>
```

Comment: How about using css files from themes built on top of SUI? Can I put the css content of those files in a .scss file and load them?

Comment: Yes, you cant put it in a new scss file and made the call later of semantic call in application.scss to overwrite it.

Comment: this post really helped with a lot of frustration. thanks a lot ricardo